# How to activate syntax highlighting for CoffeeScript in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, coffeescript

I'm running an Eclipse Luna. Additionally I installed `Nodeclipse.17.plus` via the marketplace and checked all provied tools. This also includes the Nodeclipse Coffee-Script viewer:

```
CoffeeScript Editor let's you edit *.coffee files with some advanced features.

Highlights include

- syntax highlighting
- variable autocompletion in the current namespace
- correct autoindent
```

Additionally I activated `XText Nature` for that project.

But there is still no syntax highlighting for `*.coffee`-files.

Have I done anything wrong? (By the way, the `Nodeclipse EditBox` is working, but it is not sufficient to make CoffeeScript readable for me)

The Nodeclipse CoffeeScript Viewer seems to be installed:
[image]

But it does not appear in the List of internal editors:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no satisfactory answer to your question.

On http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse-coffeescript-viewer-editor-eclipse-431 it says:

> There is problem since Eclipse 4.3.1 release https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse/issues/19
>   Get 4.3.0, e.g. as Enide Studio 0.5.x http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-studio
>   Help us if you know Eclipse XTEXT.

and

> We were looking for new owner familiar with XText technology.

To me it seems, that there are profound problems with this plugin.

I also had the problems with a missing entry in the list of internal editors after installing nodeclipse. I simply removed the plugin and reinstalled it. But than I ran into those XText-problems

[image]

and finally gave up,...

Answer (score 1):

This plugin for Coffeescript in Eclipse is a little buggy but maybe you could try it - https://github.com/adamschmideg/coffeescript-eclipse/

Installation steps are given in the README.

Comment: I think thats the one that has been forked by Nodeclipse,... https://github.com/adamschmideg/coffeescript-eclipse/network

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
1.Open "Window" -> "Preferences" -> Expand "General" and "Editors" -> Click on "File Associations" ->  "File types:". Add ".coffee" to the list if it does not appear.
2.Look for "Associated editors:" in your "File Associations" dialog then click "Add"
3.Select "Internal editors"
4.Select "Coffee-Script Viewer". Click "OK" then "OK"

Comment: The "Coffee-Script Viewer" does not appear in the list of internal editors (I updated my question with screenshots).

Comment: 1. Restart Eclipse after installation is complete.                                        2. Follow the steps above.                                                                        3. Select "*.coffee" you will see "CoffeeScript Editor (default)" under "Associated Editors".  Click "OK"

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse Pluging For Coffee Script](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse-coffeescript-viewer-editor-eclipse-431?mpc=true&mpc_state=)